# Paypal graphics not loading on step '4. Payment Information' during checkout

Tags: paypal-pro

```
Magento 1.9.4
Porto theme
Paypal Payments Pro
```

I've installed a fresh install of Magento 1.9.4. There have been no changes made to the system other than:

- installed Porto theme
- added calendar
- disabled Form Key Validation on check-out

When going to step 4. Payment Information during checkout - the graphics that show for the Paypal payment options do NOT load. Instead it shows the graphic you get when system cannot load an image and it says: "Acceptance Mark". **Why is this and how can it be fixed?** We have Paypal Payments Pro. I tried deleting Cache and re-indexing but it did not help.